# Windows Server 2012 GPOs AD SYSVOL version mismatch

Tags: windows, security, server, gpo

I'm trying to block internet for a group of users by using a Firewall with Windows Server 2012 GPO. However, I keep running in the same problem over and over again:

When I make a GPO and use the Security Filtering to choose the user group and at the Delegation tab I put Authenticated Users to read only, after that I run the command 'gpupdate /force', and using 'gpresult /r' shows that the GPO has been Denied (Security) and I've got an AD SYSVOL Mismatch.

I've tried fixing the problem with help of Google: updating Windows Server, using 'Domain Computer', etc. But nothing helped. I've uploaded some pictures if that can help:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeT5s.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was right to reduce "Authenticated users" to read and to not apply this GPO. But you have to give this "apply" right to your users group. As I can see on the screenshot, they only have read rights. They also need "apply policy" rights which can be set under advanced permissions where you took the second screenshot.

About the AD Sysvol Mismatch: try evaluate if this solves your issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2866345/ad-sysvol-version-mismatch-message-is-displayed-unexpectedly-in-the-gr